# jsr 82 connect connection is not created (failed or aborted) sometimes appear when I try to connect to Cashregister via Bluetooth rfcomm

Tags: android, bluetooth

**I'm trying to connect to my cashregister via rfcomm bluetooth on my phone Lenovo A369i using reflection like this:**

```
 BluetoothAdapter ba = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
     BluetoothDevice device = null;
     String macAddr = "00:01:90:ED:27:73";
     for (BluetoothDevice bd : ba.getBondedDevices()) 
     {
          if (bd.getAddress().equals(macAddr)) 
          {
              device = bd;
              break;
          }
      } 

Method htcMethod = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
htcMethod.invoke(device, Integer.valueOf(1));
```

And sometimes I'v get error "jsr 82 connect connection is not created (failed or aborted)"
I'v already add all bletooth permissions to androidManifest.xml
I don't know what to do, please help me...